# Spark Streaming : Receive stream for each files under the directory

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark Core and SQL to process the multiple csv files(all having different structures) under a given directory. Till now, we had to manually bring the files under the desired location and run the job.

```
 val rdd1 = sc.textFile("csv1")
 /* transformations here for rdd1 */
 val rdd2 = sc.textFile("csv2")
 /* transformations here for rdd2 */
 val rdd3 = sc.textFile("csv3")
 /* transformations here for rdd3 */
```

But now, I want to process the same using Spark Streaming as and when the files arrive to the directory. **I don't understand how would I receive the streams pertaining to a given file** and process it.
Furthermore, I will receive files after every 15 days.

How can I achieve the same ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the File Stream?

File Streams: For reading data from files on any file system compatible with the HDFS API (that is, HDFS, S3, NFS, etc.), a DStream can be created as:

Scala code:
 streamingContext.fileStreamKeyClass, ValueClass, InputFormatClass

Spark Streaming will monitor the directory dataDirectory and process any files created in that directory (files written in nested directories not supported). Note that

- The files must have the same data format.
- The files must be created in the dataDirectory by atomically moving or renaming them into the data directory.
- Once moved, the files must not be changed. So if the files are being continuously appended, the new data will not be read.

For simple text files, there is an easier method streamingContext.textFileStream(dataDirectory). And file streams do not require running a receiver, hence does not require allocating cores.

Comment: Yes I was looking into it. `val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))
val x = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("hdfs path")
val result = x.map{case (x, y) => (x.toString, y.toString)}
result.print()`. I am able to get the file content as the string value but how would i get the name of the file which I am processing ?

Comment: Also I am able to map it to specific case class. But the problem is I have to process multiple directories separately and each of the directories have a set of interrelated files .